# new dictionary from existing dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary, append, key-value

I am trying to figure out how to perform the following:

```
firstDictionary = {"firstKey" : "A", "secondKey" : "B"}
secondDictionary = {"firstKey" : 3, "secondKey" : 47}
emptyDictionary = {}

for key, value in firstDictionary, secondDictionary:
    # emptyDictionary = some sort of append method...
```

so that

```
secondDictionary = {"A" : 3, "B" : 47}
```

Comment: Will the keys be the same in both the dictionaries?

Comment: yes, same keys in both dictionaries (no more, no less)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite straight forward. All you need to do is to iterate over one of the dictionary items and essentially find the associated value of the second dictionary using the key from the first dictionary.

```
>>> firstDictionary = {"firstKey" : "A", "secondKey" : "B"}
>>> secondDictionary = {"firstKey" : 3, "secondKey" : 47}
>>> emptyDictionary = {value : secondDictionary.get(key, None) for key, value in firstDictionary.items()}
>>> print emptyDictionary
{'A': 3, 'B': 47}
```

If you are certain that both the dictionaries have the same key, then replace the dict.get construct with a dictionary indexing

```
>>> {value : secondDictionary[key] for key, value in firstDictionary.items()}
{'A': 3, 'B': 47}
```

Comment: @Zswide: If the answer works for you, please consider accepting the solution.